# OutOfMemoryException in a long running foreach loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreach, backgroundworker, out-of-memory

I have a procedure which uses 2 sql databases - this is required in order to migrate some data from DB1 to DB2. Number of records to be migrated is around 500k. To connect to these 2 databases I use EF with 2 edmx files. A `BackgroundWorker` is used to perform this operation.

The code is pretty straightforward, i.e.:

```
string userState = "(Current action description)";
int idx = 0;
foreach (var o in DB1.Records)
{
    if (((BackgroundWorker)sender.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        break;
    }

    // Check if the current record already exists in the new database, update it if it does 
    // and create a new one if it doesn't.
    NewRecord rec = DB2.NewRecords.Where(x => x.IDFromDB1 == o.ID).SingleOrDefault() ?? DB2.NewRecords.Where(x => x.UniqueID == o.UniqueID).SingleOrDefault();
    if (rec == null)
        rec = new NewRecord();

    // Since the primary key in Records table of DB1 database consists of 2 columns,
    // where ID is the first and Idx is the second, in a way that Idx marks the revision
    // and we want to select only the latest revision, we order by "Idx" in descending order
    // and take the first record.
    Record obj = DB1.Records.Where(x => x.ID == o.ID).OrderByDescending(x => x.Idx).First(); // <-- System.OutOfMemoryException after around 250k records have been processed

    /*
        ... some primitive processing code ...
    */

    if (rec.EntityKey == null)
        DB2.NewRecords.AddObject(rec);

    idx++;
    if (idx % 50 == 0)
    {
        DB2.SaveChanges();
        ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(idx, userState);
    }
}

DB2.SaveChanges();
```

The procedure threw an exception after some 250k records have been processed.
Why? Is there a better way of doing this?

**Stack trace**

```
at System.String.Concat(String str0, String str1)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmType.CreateEdmTypeIdentity(String namespaceName, String name)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmType.BuildIdentity(StringBuilder builder)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmType.get_Identity()
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.TypeUsage.BuildIdentity(StringBuilder builder)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.CollectionType.GetIdentity(TypeUsage typeUsage)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.CollectionType..ctor(TypeUsage elementType)
at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.ArgumentValidation.ValidateProject(DbExpressionBinding input, DbExpression projection)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.CreateProject(RelOpInfo sourceInfo, IEnumerable`1 outputVars)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.BuildProjection(Node relOpNode, IEnumerable`1 projectionVars)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(PhysicalProjectOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator..ctor(Command itree, Node toConvert)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.ProviderCommandInfoUtils.Create(Command command, Node node, List`1 children)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CodeGen.Process(List`1& childCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree com mandTree)
at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Span span, ReadOnlyCollection`1 compiledQueryParameters)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__0[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
at MyProject.frmPrenosIzAnalitike._worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in C:\Users\dejan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MySolution\MyProject\frmMyForm.cs:line 245
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

Comment: What bitness (32 or 64) is your process & what is the total memory in use when you see the exception?

Comment: Maybe you should rethink your tooling. I would use tools like SSIS. Their designed for that type of tasks.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @Chris the process is 32-bit and I haven't noted the total memory in use, but I guess it was out of memory for real :-)

Comment: @Sascha, I need to parse and apply some logic to the migrated data, which is why EF was the best choice for me.

Comment: You can do this with SSIS, too. The idea of SSIS is a bit different as it operates on relational data, so the efforts may vary. Though it is usually easier to write functional logic, logic based on set theory is more efficient in terms of data processing when working with relational databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you're adding new entities to the context all the time. You basically don't want to load 250K entities in memory.

Just detach them when you don't need them anymore

```
// Assuming DB1 is your object context
Record obj = DB1.Records.Where(x => x.ID == o.ID).OrderByDescending(x => x.Idx).First();

...

DB1.Detach(obj); // <------ Detaches from context, removes from memory
```

Same thing for `DB2` and created entities.

Comment: sounds legit, I will give it a try as soon as possible and then post back